# I don't understand why it's showing me an error of function, indentation and others

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just a newbie trying to get used to python, and I made a challenge for myself, to make a store type of thing, that asks you how much money do you have and how much something costs, and then it says if its enough or not. Yesterday did something like this and it worked, now I guess im missing something. I'm getting not only one but a few errors at times.

```
def my_store():
    print("Welcome to our store!")
    money = input('How much money do you have? ')
    price = input('How much does the product cost? ')

    if price < money or money == price:
        return "You have enough money! You can make your purchase!"
    if price > money:
        difference = price - money
        return "You are {} short for {} :( Come back next time!".format(difference, money)

print (my_store)

Error - <function my_store at 0x000002262DB77F70>
```

And for example if i dont use `def`, it shows me this error:

```
print("Welcome to our store!")
money = input('How much money do you have? ')
price = input('How much does the product cost? ')
if price < money or money == price:
    return "You have enough money! You can make your purchase!"
if price > money:
    difference = price - money
    return"You are {} short for {} :( Come back next time!".format(difference, money)

print (my_store)

Error - SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

And I get others if I change something else. I'm really trying to get the hang of it, but I'm not succeeding. Can anyone explain or help?

Comment: What's not clear? `return` is only used in functions. We can't help with anything else unless you post it... Please consider going over [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: in the first example, you simply forgot to call the function - `print (my_store)` is I presume supposed to be `print (my_store())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting an error on your first code, it just does what you wrote. You printed the `my_store`, which is a function.

You need to call a function to execute it, and then it will return the value to you. Like this:

```py
def my_store():
    print("Welcome to our store!")
    money = input('How much money do you have? ')
    price = input('How much does the product cost? ')

    if price < money or money == price:
        return "You have enough money! You can make your purchase!"
    if price > money:
        difference = price - money
        return "You are {} short for {} :( Come back next time!".format(difference, money)

print(my_store()) # note those `()` after `my_store`.
```

This will fix your bug, but this time you will literally get an error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(my_store())
  File "x.py", line 9, in my_store
    difference = price - money
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

This is because you are trying to subtract a `str` from another `str`, you can't. Strings do not support subtraction. You have to convert your variables to an integer via `int` function.

Answer (score 0):

`return` can only be used inside functions. So you need to replace every `return`-statement with a call to `print()` like so:

```
print("You have enough money! You can make your purchase!")
```

This applies to your code without `def`.